# VBA - Hide rows macro limit

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the code below to hide all blank cells on my sheet. How do I set the hide range to 100 so after cell 100 if the remaining ones are blank it doesn't hide them. Only cells within the 1-100 limit get hidden if blank.

```
Sub HideRow()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projects Dashboard")
    Dim LRowC, LRowD, LRowF, LRowH, LRow As Long
    LRowC = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LRowD = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LRowF = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LRowH = ws.Range("H" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LRowC, LRowD, LRowF, LRowH)

    Dim I As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ws.Rows.Hidden = False
    For I = LRow To 7 Step -1
        If ws.Range("C" & I).Text = "" And ws.Range("D" & I).Text = "" And ws.Range("F" & I).Text = "" And ws.Range("I" & I).Text = "" Then
            ws.Rows(I).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next I
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `LRowH` is based on column `H` but you check the values in column `I` when you check if content is empty. Is this wanted?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, `column I`?, please review the code again.

Comment: From your code: `And ws.Range("I" & I).Text`, please review the code again.

Comment: Sorry, missed that last range.

Comment: Please clarify your question, are you wanting to stop after the first 100 empty cells or 100 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question and code, it seems that you would want limit your LRow value to be a max of 100.

Should be as simple as adding one line of code:

```
...    
LRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LRowC, LRowD, LRowF, LRowH)

If LRow > 100 Then LRow = 100

Dim I As Long
...
```

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thanks a lot Rey.